# Django model operations with foreign key and double underscore

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm new to Django and just being curious to know more. 
Assuming I have two models defined as follows:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    Item1 = models.Charfield()
    description = models.Charfield()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    ItemTypes = models.CharField(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When trying to reference or use the model, you use them like this (still assuming):

```
something = ModelB.objects.filter(ItemType__Item)
```

My question is on the double underscore `__`.

I'm just curious to know:

1. What does the code at the back end look like.
2. Is there a valid syntax with a triple underscore or a single underscore?

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote the code to be valid Django models:

```
class ModelA(models.Model):
    item1 = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()

class ModelB(models.Model):
    item_types = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

```
things = ModelB.objects.filter(item_types__item1="the-item-name")
```

Q1. What does the code at the back end look like.

A1. The resulting SQL query is:

```
SELECT b.*
FROM ModelB b, ModelB a
WHERE b.item_types_id = a.id
AND a.item1 = 'the-item-name'
```

The `item_types` ForeignKey column is created as `item_types_id` in the database. All Django database tables contain a column named `id` if a primary key is not specified.

Q2. Is there a valid syntax with a triple underscore or a single underscore?

A2. There is no triple underscore. A single underscore is valid for use in column names.